# SignalR(Hub) can send a message except signal maker?

Tags: asp.net, signalr

I'm studying SingalR(https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR).

I'm really want to send a message to all connection **except the person who makes a event.**

For example,

In Chatting application, there is three client(A,B,C).

Client A type a message, "Hello" and clikc submit.

Clients.addMessage(data); send "Hello" to All Cleint(include cleint A)

I want to send "Hello" only Client B and C.

How can I achieve it?

```
// I think this can get all Clients, right?
var clients = Hub.GetClients<Chat>();
```

Comment: @dfowler Could you help me a litte ^^?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There's no way to filter message on the server today, but you can block messages to the caller from the client side. If you look at some of the samples on signalr, you'll see that they assign each client a generated id to the client in a method (usually called join). Whenever you invoke a method from the hub, pass the id of the calling client, then on the client side do a check to make sure the id of the client isn't the same as the caller. e.g.

```
public class Chat : Hub { 
    public void Join() {
        // Assign the caller and id
        Caller.id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    }

    public void DoSomething() {
        // Pass the caller's id back to the client along with any extra data
        Clients.doIt(Caller.id, "value");
    }
}
```

Client side

```
var chat = $.connection.chat;
chat.doIt = function(id, value) {
   if(chat.id === id) {
      // The id is the same so do nothing
      return;
   }

   // Otherwise do it!
   alert(value);
};
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: I think this is really helpful for me. Thank you for answer. Also Thank you for great framework. bless you.

Comment: Did the id property changed since your reply? I cant get the id on client side, returns undefined.

Answer (score 5):

It is now (v1.0.0) possible by using `Clients.Others` property in your `Hub`.

E.g.: `Clients.Others.addMessage(data)` calls the method `addMessage` on all clients except the caller.